# Scheduling a local notification

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to show a toast notification at times defined by my app just before it shuts down. For example, when the game is minimized I would like a notification to say 1 message after 5min 30s and another toast to appear with a different message after 3hrs 27mins (just random examples). This functionality exists on other platforms but doesnt seem well documented for WP

Answer (score 0):

There nothing like this on Windows Phone. You have to use push notifications. Only alarms and reminders can be scheduled.